# How to sum all same name item at the datagridview in vb?

Tags: vb.net

Assume that I have a form, there is a dategridview1. I have several items already added in the dgv (ex.notebook, pen, paper, eraser, etc.)

Now, I want to sum all the quantity of let say notebook. Label1 will display the sum of all notebooks added in the dgv.

Thanks

Comment: Show what's you've tried and specifically where you're having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

my commands may be off but i'd imagine it would go something like this,

```
dim sum as int/double    
for each row as dgv.row in datagridview1.rows
       if row.column(0).ToString = samename then
         sum += cint(row.column(2))
       end if
    next
```